# A little bit complicated pandas pivot-table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have following data as data frame (of course more rows):

| FloorId | FloorLabel | RoomId | RoomLabel | Area | Tenant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Floor 1 | 4 | Room 1 | 10 | AQQ |
| 1 | Floor 1 | 5 | Room 2 | 20 | AQQ |
| 2 | Floor 1 | 6 | Room 1 | 15 | ZAA |
| 3 | Floor 2 | 7 | Room 1 | 25 | ZAA |
| 3 | Floor 2 | 8 | Room 2 | 33 | AQQ |

As you can see ids are unique and labels aren't.

I need as a result something like that:

| FloorLabel | RoomLabel | Area | Tenant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Floor 1 | Room 1 | 10 | AQQ |
|  | Room 2 | 20 | AQQ |
| Floor 1 | Room 1 | 15 | ZAA |
| Floor 2 | Room 1 | 25 | ZAA |
|  | Room 2 | 33 | AQQ |

Rooms grouped under floors.

I tried many combinations of pandas pivot_table and groupby but the best result gave me:

```py
result = pd.pivot_table(rooms, index = ['FloorId', 'RoomId'],
                                     values = ['FloorLabel', 'RoomLabel', 'Area', 'Tenant'],
                                     aggfunc = {
                                         'FloorLabel': sum,
                                         'RoomLabel': sum,
                                         'Area': sum,
                                         'Tenant': sum
                                     })
```

but I don't have any idea how to change it in expected result.

Is it even possible to get the result I expect with pandas? Or maybe I need to use a different library?

---

Edit:

I found solution. I don't know if its optimal, but it seems to work.

```py
res = rooms.groupby(['FloorId', 'RoomId']).agg(FloorLabel = ('FloorLabel', sum), 
                                               RoomLabel = ('RoomLabel', sum), 
                                               Area = ('Area', sum), 
                                               Tenant = ('Tenant', sum))
res = res.set_index(['FloorLabel', 'RoomLabel'])
```

Comment: you can try `result.set_index(['FloorLabel','RoomLabel'])`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and the result is not expected one. Check in question. I need to "group" all rooms under their parent floors.

Comment: try `result.droplevel(1).set_index(['FloorLabel','RoomLabel'],append=True)`?

Comment: Thanks, but I think I found proper solution. I have to test it and I'll put it here. Your first answer gave me a clue.

Comment: glad that you found solution without any help...happy coding **:)**